# Javascript simple image gallery

Tags: javascript, html, image-gallery

im trying to make a simple javascript photo gallery, in which u can change the img by 2 buttons, to the previous one and to the next one, there are 9 images and if the 9th image is shown and u press next, it should show the first one img, could anyone help me please?
My code doesnt work.

HTML:

```
<body>
<img src="img (1).jpg" alt="" height="200">
<button id="previous">previous image</button>
<button id="next">next image</button>
```

JS:

```
<script>
let counter = 1;
let img = document.querySelector("img");
let changeImg = function (type) {
    if (type == 1) {
        counter++   
    } else {
        counter--
    }
    if (counter <= 0) {
        counter = 9
    }
    img.setAttribute("src", "img ("+counter+").jpeg")
}

let previous = document.getElementById("previous")
let next = document.getElementById("next")

previous.addEventListener("click", chaneImg(1))
next.addEventListener("click", changeImg(2))
```

thanks

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is with the way you have added your listeners:

```
previous.addEventListener("click", changeImg(1))
```

should be

```
previous.addEventListener("click", (e) => changeImg(1))
```

The first one calls changeImage on load.

```js
let counter = 1;
let img = document.querySelector("img");
let changeImg = function(type) {
  if (type == 1) {
    counter++
  } else {
    counter--
  }
  if (counter <= 0) {
    counter = 9
  }
  img.setAttribute("src", "img (" + counter + ").jpeg")
}

let previous = document.getElementById("previous")
let next = document.getElementById("next")

previous.addEventListener("click", (_e) => changeImg(1))
next.addEventListener("click", (_e) => changeImg(2))
```

```html
<body>
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/Att5gPe.jpg" alt="" height="200">
  <button id="previous">previous image</button>
  <button id="next">next image</button>
</body>
```

Comment: I tried it and now it loads the first one img (1).jpg , and also the src works after i click on previous / next perfectly, but for some reason the images are still not showing, not even the 1st one when i click on next and then previous back to 1st

Comment: I was using +jpeg from the code, but it should have been +jpg only, thanks you very much all works fine now :)

Answer (score 2):

Not tested, but a couple of things I see are:

typo on this line:

```
previous.addEventListener("click", changeImg(1))
```

`chaneImg(1)` to `changeImg(1)`

You also don't have a condition to check the inverse of this:

```
if (counter <= 0) {
    counter = 9
}
```

so try adding

```
if (counter >= 9) {
    counter = 1
}
```